# C++ OpenGL TGA Loading Failing

Tags: c++, opengl, load, tga

I've been working through a basic OpenGl tutorial on loading a TGA file, to be used as a texture on a 3d object. I've been able to load data from the TGA header, but when I attempt to load the actual image data, it fails. I'm not sure where it is going wrong. Here is my texture loading class:

Header file:

```
    struct TGA_Header 
{
    GLbyte  ID_Length;
    GLbyte  ColorMapType;
    GLbyte  ImageType;
    // Color map specifications
    GLbyte firstEntryIndex[2];      
    GLbyte colorMapLength[2];
    GLbyte colorMapEntrySize;

    //image specification
    GLshort xOrigin;
    GLshort yOrigin;
    GLshort ImageWidth;
    GLshort ImageHeight;
    GLbyte  PixelDepth;
    GLbyte ImageDescriptor;
};

class Texture
{
public:
    Texture(string in_filename, string in_name = "");
    ~Texture();

public:
    unsigned short  width;
    unsigned short  height;
    unsigned int    length;
    unsigned char   type;   
    unsigned char   *imageData;
    unsigned int    bpp;
    unsigned int    texID;

    string          name;

    static vector<Texture *> textures;

private:
    bool loadTGA(string filename);
    bool createTexture(unsigned char *imageData, int width, int height, int type);

    void swap(unsigned char * ori, unsigned char * dest, GLint size);
    void flipImage(unsigned char * image, bool flipHorizontal, bool flipVertical, GLushort width, GLushort height, GLbyte bpp);
};
```

Here is the load TGA function in the cpp:

```
bool Texture::loadTGA(string filename)
{
    TGA_Header TGAheader;

    ifstream file( filename.data(), std::ios::in, std::ios::binary );

    //make sure the file was opened properly
    if (!file.is_open() )
        return false;

    if( !file.read( (char *)&TGAheader, sizeof(TGAheader) ) )
        return false;


    //make sure the image is of a type we can handle
    if( TGAheader.ImageType != 2 )
        return false;

    width = TGAheader.ImageWidth;
    height = TGAheader.ImageHeight;
    bpp = TGAheader.PixelDepth;

    if( width < 0   ||              // if the width or height is less than 0, than
        height <= 0 ||              // the image is corrupt
        (bpp != 24 && bpp != 32) )  // make sure we are of the correct bit depth
    {
        return false;
    }

    //check for an alpha channel
    GLuint type = GL_RGBA;
    if ( bpp == 24 )
        type = GL_RGB;

    GLuint bytesPerPixel = bpp / 8;

    //allocate memory for the TGA so we can read it
    GLuint imageSize = width * height * bytesPerPixel;
    imageData = new GLubyte[imageSize];

    if ( imageData == NULL )
        return false;

    //make sure we are in the correct position to load the image data
    file.seekg(-imageSize, std::ios::end);

    // if something when wrong, make sure we free up the memory
    //NOTE: It never gets past this point. The conditional always fails.
    if ( !file.read( (char *)imageData, imageSize ) )
    {
        delete imageData;

        return false;
    }

    //more code is down here, but it doesnt matter because it does not pass the above function
}
```

It seems to load some data, but it keeps returning that it failed. Any help on why would be greatly appreciated. Appologies if it gets a bit wordy, but I'm not sure what is or is not significant.

UPDATE:
So, I just rewrote the function. The ifsteam I was using, seemed to be the cause of the problem. Specifically, it would try and load far more bytes of data than I had entered. I don't know the cause of the behavior, but I've listed my functioning code below. Thank you every one for your help.

Comment: What did you learn from debugging?

Comment: Unfortunately, not much. The imageData pointer definately seems to load data of some kind, but it fails the conditional anyway.

Comment: note that you should use 'delete [] imageData', that is not related to your current problem though

Comment: @rotoglup Thank you, I've made the change. Why is it, I should use that one as opposed to 'delete imageData'?

Comment: @Donutfiend84 This is a c++ rule, as you allocate your imageData with the `new type[]` construct, you have to use the matching `delete []`construct. You'll easily be able to find more details if you feel like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I changed from using an ifstream to a FILE. The ifstream, was trying to load far more bytes than I had listed in the arguments. Here is the new code. (NOTE: It still needs optomized. I believe there are some unused variables floating around, but it works perfectly.). Thanks again everyone for your help.

The header file:

```
    //struct to hold tga data
struct TGA_Header
{
    GLbyte  ID_Length;
    GLbyte  ColorMapType;
    GLbyte  ImageType;
    // Color map specifications
    GLbyte firstEntryIndex[2];      
    GLbyte colorMapLength[2];
    GLbyte colorMapEntrySize;

    //image specification
    GLshort xOrigin;
    GLshort yOrigin;
    GLshort ImageWidth;
    GLshort ImageHeight;
    GLbyte  PixelDepth;
    GLbyte ImageDescriptor;
};

class Texture
{
public:
    //functions
    Texture(string in_filename, string in_name = "");
    ~Texture();

public:
    //vars
    unsigned char   *imageData;
    unsigned int    texID;

    string          name;

    //temp global access point for accessing all loaded textures
    static vector<Texture *> textures;

private:
    //can add additional load functions for other image types
    bool loadTGA(string filename);
    bool createTexture(unsigned char *imageData, int width, int height, int type);

    void swap(unsigned char * ori, unsigned char * dest, GLint size);
    void flipImage(unsigned char * image, bool flipHorizontal, bool flipVertical, GLushort width, GLushort height, GLbyte bpp);
};

#endif
```

Here is the load TGA function:

```
    bool Texture::loadTGA(string filename)
{
    //var for swapping colors
    unsigned char colorSwap = 0;

    GLuint type;
    TGA_Header TGAheader;

    FILE* file = fopen(filename.c_str(), "rb");

    unsigned char Temp_TGAheader[18];

    //check to make sure the file loaded
    if( file == NULL )
        return false;   

    fread(Temp_TGAheader, 1, sizeof(Temp_TGAheader), file);

    //pull out the relavent data. 2 byte data (short) must be converted
    TGAheader.ID_Length = Temp_TGAheader[0];
    TGAheader.ImageType = Temp_TGAheader[2];
    TGAheader.ImageWidth = *static_cast<unsigned short*>(static_cast<void*>(&Temp_TGAheader[12]));
    TGAheader.ImageHeight = *static_cast<unsigned short*>(static_cast<void*>(&Temp_TGAheader[14]));
    TGAheader.PixelDepth = Temp_TGAheader[16];


    //make sure the image is of a type we can handle
    if( TGAheader.ImageType != 2 || TGAheader.ImageWidth <= 0 || TGAheader.ImageHeight <= 0 )
    {
        fclose(file);
        return false;
    }

    //set the type
    if ( TGAheader.PixelDepth == 32 )
    {
        type = GL_RGBA;
    } 
    else if ( TGAheader.PixelDepth == 24 ) 
    {
        type = GL_RGB;
    }
    else 
    {
        //incompatable image type
        return false;
    }


    //remember bits != bytes. To convert we need to divide by 8
    GLuint bytesPerPixel = TGAheader.PixelDepth / 8;

    //The Memory Required For The TGA Data  
    unsigned int imageSize = TGAheader.ImageWidth * TGAheader.ImageHeight * bytesPerPixel;// Calculate 

    //request the needed memory
    imageData = new GLubyte[imageSize];

    if ( imageData == NULL ) // just in case
        return false;

    if( fread(imageData, 1, imageSize, file) != imageSize )
    {       
        //Kill it
        delete [] imageData;
        fclose(file);                                           
        return false;   
    }       

    fclose(file);

    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < imageSize; x +=bytesPerPixel)  
    {
        colorSwap = imageData[x];       
        imageData[x] = imageData[x + 2];        
        imageData[x + 2] = colorSwap;   
    }   

    createTexture( imageData, TGAheader.ImageWidth, TGAheader.ImageHeight, type );

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with C++, sorry.

Are you sure this line `file.seekg(-imageSize, std::ios::end);` is not supposed to be `file.seekg(headerSize, std::ios::start);` ?

Makes more sense to seek from start than from end.

You should also check for `ColorMapType != 0`.

P.S. Here `if( width < 0 || height <=0` width check should be `<=` as well.

Comment: I had tried: 
    file.seekg(18, std::ios::beg);
 
 But since it didn't seem to effect the outcome, I changed it back.

Comment: I would not consider it a good practice to stick to solutions that "just work" when they are clearly misplaced. In this case it should be `beg` and some sort of `SizeOf(tgaHeader)` instead of `18`. As for the question - debugger is your friend - check whats wrong with that `file.read` you have.

Comment: You should also check for `ColorMapType != 0`

Comment: Just an update, I've found that seeking backwards will cause problems, as Krom mentioned. Specifically, I neglected the footer of the TGA.

Comment: That was I referring to. Usually there's no footer, but in some cases it would corrupt the image. Still that would not fail the loading (any binary sequence of required length will be valid for glGenTexture).

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be depending on the TGA algorithm which do not support compressed TGA.

Make sure you do not compress the TGA and that the TGA order (less important) is in a Bottom Left origin.

I usually work with GIMP and at the moment of the same, uncheck the RLE compression and put the Bottom Left alignment.

Comment: Thats why there's a check: `if( TGAheader.ImageType != 2 ) return false;`. Type 2 stands for uncompressed TGA. If the TGA order was upside-down it would not affect the loading, just displaying image upside-down in render.